# Digital App using my physical product's Trademark Name

Tags: trademark

I make a physical product with a Registered Trademark going back to 1996.  Recently a website has been advertising that it can do what my physical product can do, and is using both my trademark and my name and story in its branding and sales pitch.  Because the two products are in different classes (a web app vs a piece of furniture), but are advertising that they do the same thing, do i have any recourse to keep them from using both my trademark and my name (and photo as well,no less)

The website app can sort of do what my physical product can do, but in reality, its missing a key element that makes my product exceptional and theirs quite inferior.  My product is a non-reversing mirror, which allows direct and ongoing eye contact with a life sized 3D version of yourself.  Essentially it gives viewers an accurate and interacting view of what they look like and what they are like.  Theirs is a website photo app which while it does show you without being reversed, because its using a camera, there is no eye contact possible, plus it's small, flat and lens distorted.  No interactivity possible.

For sure, it could confuse people about the quality of the concept of seeing and interacting with yourself without being reversed, which my trademarked product has been building its name for almost 30 years.
thanks for any advice and opinions